# How to turn of caching in wamp?

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, wamp

I am working on wordpress running on WAMP. I edit my functions.php file to include a taxonomy like the following:

```
function player_taxonomy() {
register_taxonomy('players', 'post', array(
'hierarchical' => false, 'label' => 'Players',
'query_var' => true, 'rewrite' => true));
}
add_action('init', 'player_taxonomy', 0);
```

which adds a custom taxonomy into my post creation page. Everything works great, now I try to remove the code from the file, but the taxonomy still remains in the post creation page. I suspect it to be a caching issue. I have tried running the opcache_reset(), clearing the browser cache as well as set opcache.enable=0 in my php.ini file. Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: What version of PHP are you using

Comment: Are you using a cache plugin within WP

Comment: PHP 5.6.25 
No I don't have any cache plugins with WP

Comment: Have you found the way to disable this php file caching in wamp?